# How to convert mp4 to avi?

Tags: c#

I need to play avi file in my windows application.But i kept files are in mp4 format(because of size issue).Here i want to convert and play  that mp4 file into avi(programatically).is it possible ? if possible means how?

Comment: @utility i didnt try any method. i just want to know is there any possiblities we have to convert.I checked in net they have given only avi to mp4 convertion

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Third party resource such as [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) integrate the package in code and then you can convert.

Comment: may i know the steps to integrate this ffmpeg in my application

Comment: You need to read the documentation its usually addition of an extension/ package with its own classes where you pass in your video as input and get your converted video as output. FFmpeg is really great for C# have used it hence recommended it